# changing 3d model at run time

Tags: java, 3d, rendering

I am new in 3D modelling, I am not expecting exact ans but any hint, link or direction will good for me. I am working in java and i have to work with 3D model now. So its like, I will make a model (using XYZ software) and define some parts of it lets say part1, part2. Then at run time on browser user have a drop down to select the part and then he give some value , now i want to change the 3d model according to that value of that part (that could be length,width etc) and user should be able to see that on browser. 
First, Is it possible, changing dimension at runtime (I can make some restriction also)?
Second , Any hint , library or logic direction will be great help.

I can go for any language , any software now as because I am about to start from scratch. 
If I haven't made my question clear, do let me know.

One solution I can think of is for different possibilities ,I should have different model already in background, and load that one , whose dimensions matches with user selection. 
OR any other suggestions ??

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear in that you say that you are using Java but can go for any language...

I am making the assumption here that you are indeed using Java. There are several libraries available for Java that support "rendering" of 3d objects. The level of abstraction depends on the individual library/framework.

Some example of what are referred to as low-level libraries:
Java 3D, (OpenGL wrappers)lwjgl, JOGL.

Some higher level frameworks:
JMonkeyEngine, Andor3D, Ogre4J.

I only list a few as an exhaustive list is not what SO is for, nor am I going to compare them for the same reason.

If you want to code the loading of assets, how they render, how they are stored at runtime, how they should be rendered then you will probably be going with the lower level ones. Going with a framework means you care less about what low level graphics library you use rather what the framework can offer.

Your second set of questions really deal with details that you would only need to worry about after the initial choice. If you have model loading code then you can just load a new model triggered by an event.

Edit: Only caught that you said run in browser, if that is a requirement then that complicates things. You would probably need to go another route, perhaps WebGL and javascript, or three.js.

Again without a more specific question, can't really give a more concrete answer.

Edit : Reuest per comment: 
Although flash support is being phased out of web-browsers there are several libraries available. papervision, unity3d-web, away 3d. I have away3d myself on a small project for a simulation visualisation project. It was pretty easy to use, but for what I needed perfomance was not good, but then again I would not recommend using flash for 3d either. That said it has probably improved since then.

Comment: Really thanks for your ans. Yes I mentioned that I am working in java , with the intention that before suggestion u understood my background. Second part is yes, because I am starting with fresh one, so I can learn any new language to make it happen. Third, yes It should be user browser.

Comment: Lets say there is cube shape, and run time user change the length, width or height, so can i change these specific in model at run time?? or other way i can do is, give the user option in selection of length , width or height.. and user can select only these values and i will load that model accordingly ?? , if it is still not clear do let me know.. Will flash+action script can do this in 3d ?

Comment: Start into a library, figure out the basics, i.e how to create. render objects, applying matrices, lighting, textures etc rather than specific problems you think you have. Once you know how the basics, then expand by replacing the hard coded things with user input. Updated answer with Flash related libraries